Automatically erasing a "folder" in gmail
By "folder" I intend an element of the labels architecture of gmail. (You can create a label, and a sublabel, and make a "filter" to sent all mails veryfing certain criteria in that sublable.) Is it possible to have an automated job of some kind in gmail erasing everyday at a given hour all mail from a given sublabel ? Or all sent mail ?

Anything that can he done in Gmail search and Filters can be done programmatically using the API. Whyvare you trying to do this?

This could be done by using the Gmail Service (Class GmailApp) and a time-driven trigger from Google Apps Script. For a broad introduction to Google Apps Script please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview.
TLDR: Google Apps Script is "low code" platform that makes it easy to extend and automate some task in Google apps like Gmail. It uses JavaScript as programming language and include services like the Gmail Service (Class Gmail). Also, it includes two categories of triggers, simple and installable.
It's worth noting that the first link includes a Samples section among other resources to help people to start with Google Apps Script.

Thank you for the migration and for the answer. I just finished scheduling the script I wrote ! Would you perhaps know if there is a python API for these script ?

@Olórin There is a Google Apps Script API so you could call a function in Apps Script from other platforms / programming languages. P.D. You might ask for a software recommendation in [softwarerecs.se].

There is a "triggers" section in an apps project that allows you to schedule, with some time granularity (but not a precise time of the day with frequency), the execution of a given function (maybe more, did not try as I just coded one function). But I prefer a python script hosted locally on some server that something hosted on google servers, it minimizes the stuff you have on the google account you use.

Feel free to use Python. As I mentioned, you might ask for a software recommendation, i.e. a Gmail library for Python, in [softwarerecs.se]. If you have programming questions usually they belong to [so]. The overlaping between this site and the other is on questions about using a web app to edit/run code from a end-user development perspective.
